# vite app.js не подключается - connection timeout. Неверный путь?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

Проблема с подключением vite. Сейчас имеется проект на Laravel, который - часть корп.портала Bitrix, хочу подключить к нему vuejs, vue-router через vite.  Проблема в том, что мой адрес сервиса -https://portal.suite.ru/services/development/ .
По установке всё отлично.
В blade вставляю @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']).

Запускаю npm run dev, захожу на страничку
и получаю

> GET https://portal.suite.ru:5173/@vite/client
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT portal.aksf.ru/:24
>
> GET https://portal.suite.ru:5173/resources/css/app.css
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT portal.aksf.ru/:24
>
> GET https://portal.suite.ru:5173/resources/js/app.js
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

TrustProxies разрешены.

public/hot перед новым тестом удаляю всегда.

Права на файлы максимальные.

php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear

```
 .env - APP_URL=https://portal.suite.ru
 vite.config.js  =      
   server: {
            https: true,
            hmr : {
                host: 'portal.suite.ru',  
            },
        },
```

Получаю

> https://portal.suite.ru:5173/resources/css/app.css
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

Казалось бы, почти то, что нужно, но у меня https://portal.suite.ru/services/development/ , поэтому по идее ссылка для подключения vite должна выглядеть примерно так https://portal.suite.ru:5173/services/development/resources/css/app.css . Сказано - сделано, правлю на
@vite(['services/development/resources/css/app.css', 'services/development/resources/js/app.js']),
получаю

> GET
> https://portal.aksf.ru:5173/services/development/resources/js/app.js
> net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

И я зашёл в тупик. Прошу помощи.

В vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";


export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        https: true,
        hmr : {
            host: 'portal.aksf.ru',  
        },
    },

    plugins: [
        vue(),

        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

В package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.1",
        "vue": "^3.2.36",
        "vue-loader": "^17.0.1"
    }
}
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

npm run dev отображает без ошибок

```
  VITE v4.4.9  ready in 725 ms

  ➜  Local:   https://127.0.0.1:5173/

  LARAVEL v9.52.15  plugin v0.7.8

  ➜  APP_URL: https://portal.suite.ru
```

---

```
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    hmr: {
        clientPort: 5173,
        host: 'localhost',
    },
}
```

> VITE v4.4.9  ready in 416 ms
>
> ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/

> ➜  Network:  http://10.12.11.300:5173/